Replace li with span in my account menu in woocommerce
I'm having problem replace the li to span. Here is my code below.
// Replace WooCommerce My Account Menu HTML
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_account_menu_html', 10, 1 );

function custom_account_menu_html( $items ) {

    // Remove existing menu items
    $items = array(
        'dashbaord' => '<li>sdfasdfs</li>'
    );

    implode('', $items);
    return $items;
}

this code is working my issue is that it's added inside the li instead of replacing it which makes sense.

I tried the other way when re-assign li in foreach then imploding it but it's having an error. So this is my second solution because I don't have any choice. Empty the original menu array and replace it with the new one using woocommerce_before_account_navigation feel free to add more solution.
<?php

// Replace WooCommerce My Account Menu HTML
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_account_menu_html', 10, 1 );

function custom_account_menu_html( $items ) {
    $items = array(); // or you can use unset 
    return $items;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_navigation', 'create_my_own_menu_woo' );

/**
 * Function for `woocommerce_before_account_navigation` action-hook.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function create_my_own_menu_woo(){
    echo "<span>asfdafsd</span>
            <span>asfdafsd</span>";
}

